# How do I fix this "WNDPROC" message in my code?

Tags: python

I've made a pomodoro code and whenever I start it, I get this message in my terminal:

[image: This message shows up in the terminal]

I am not sure what this even means or how to solve it.

I've tried making changes to my "show_toast" functions whenever they're used but they seem to have no effect on the outcome. I am really not sure how to deal with it

Here's my code

```py
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import time
import os


#Setting up notification messages
startWork = ToastNotifier()
startRest = ToastNotifier()
endOfSession = ToastNotifier()




def min_sec(minutes):
    return minutes * 60


def countdown(t, label):
    while t:
        min, sec = divmod(t, 60)
        #t//60 -> minutes
        #t%60 -> seconds
        print(f"{label}: {min:02d}:{sec:02d}", end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1


def pomodoro(work, rest, cycle):

    w = min_sec(work)
    r = min_sec(rest)

    for i in range(cycle):
        print("CYCLE ", i+1)
        startWork.show_toast("WORK", "Start working", icon_path = None, duration= 3, threaded= True)
        countdown(w, "Work")

        os.system("clear||cls")
        print("CYCLE ", i+1)
        startRest.show_toast("REST", "Rest until time's up", icon_path = None, duration= 3,     threaded= True)
        countdown(r, "Rest")


    #after the for loop, the following notification should show up

    endMessage = f"Cycles completed: {cycle} \nminutes worked: {work * cycle}"

    endOfSession.show_toast("Session Done", endMessage, duration= 3)



work = int(input("Enter working time(min): "))
rest = int(input("Enter resting time(min): "))
cycle = int(input("Enter number of cycles: "))


pomodoro(work, rest, cycle)
#end of code
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Don't add links to images of text, or inline images of text: [show the actual text](/help/how-to-ask), and put it in code fences if that makes sense.

Comment: Looks like a bug in win10toast: https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/issues/112 There's a patch, but it hasn't been merged.